# query_post or single-[cpt].php?

Tags: posts, query

php query_posts( 'post_type=listing');

Or

single-listing.php?

According to my reading I have presumed that to display a custom post type all I need to do is copy my single.php and rename it accordingly. It doesn't work for me and I just get the title.

Should I persist, am I misunderstanding something or what might I be doing wrong.

Or do I also need to use query_post?

Comment: You need to show the code of your single-listing.php, for starters.

Comment: And your CPT code.

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for your interest.  Here's my custom post type plugin: pastebin.com/pKzt5xmD and this is my single-listing.php: http://pastebin.com/vh2FXpMz  I guess I should also say that I am using Gravity Forms to submit content to this post type.  I have some success with this directory page using archive-listing.php  neighbourgood.co.uk/listing/

Answer (score -1):

Try refreshing your permalinks. That is, simply visit your settings -> permalinks page. Then check `single-listing.php` again.

WordPress may need nudging to pay attention to your new file.

Comment: Thanks vancoder but, no joy with that.  I wonder if it has something to do with the form.